# Validate Email before Ajax Load using: jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am new to jquery. I've been researching and am having trouble trying to validate email address before ajax load using query.validate.min.js.

**I want to validate the form and only call app.ajax.load if the input is valid.** Whatever condition I put in place before the ajax load the form is still posting without validation also ignoring my call back. (Which is a "Thank you" message)

Can someone help me with the condition or do I need to write a seperate function to validate?

```
$('#emailsignup_form').validate({
rules: {
email: {
required: true;
email:true
}
},
messages: {
email: "Invalid Email",
},

submitHandler: function(form){
    app.ajax.load({
         reqName : 'emailSubmit',
         url: '$httpUrl('Bronto-OptIn')$?email=' + $('#email').val(), 
         selector : '#emailbox',
         callback: function(responseText, textStatus) { }
    });
            return false;
});

});


<form id="emailsignup_form" name="emailsignup_form" method="post" action="$httpUrl('Bronto-OptIn', 'fid', 'information')$">
<div class="fl"><input class="email-signup-input" type="text" title="Enter Your Email Address" value="Enter Your Email Address" name="email" id="email" /></div>
<div class="fl"><button class="email-signup-btn" value="Submit" name="submitemail" id="submitemail">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're asking about the Validate plugin but I don't see `.validate()` used anyplace in your code.

Comment: @ Sparky, As mentioned in my initial question above - I am trying to figure out where I am suppose to be putting the .validate().

Comment: Have you checked official docs? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Yes, I have edited the code to include .validate as per Sparky recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hazardous for you to assign an `input` `name` of `"email"`, when there is also a `rule` called `"email"`.  Technically it will work, but as you can see below, it can potentially lead to great confusion.  Example:  the `email` inside your `messages:` was intended to be assigned to the `input` named `email`, or to the `rule` called `email`?

---

You have some syntax errors in your `rules` and `messages`...

```
rules: {
email: { 
required: true; // <-- semicolon incorrect, must be a comma
email:true
}
},
messages: {
email: "Invalid Email", // <-- should define a message for each corresponding rule
},
```

Should be something like...

```
    rules: {
        email: { // the field name
            required: true,
            email: true // the rule
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: { // the field name
            required: "this is required",
            email: "Invalid email" // the rule's message
        }
    },
```

And your `submitHandler:` is malformed...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    app.ajax.load({
        reqName: 'emailSubmit',
        url: '$httpUrl('Bronto - OptIn')$?email=' + $('#email').val(),
        selector: '#emailbox',
        callback: function (responseText, textStatus) {}
    });
    return false; 
}); // <-- this is not correct
```

Should be something more like this (assuming your ajax function is correct)...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    app.ajax.load({
        reqName: 'emailSubmit',
        url: '$httpUrl('Bronto - OptIn')$?email=' + $('#email').val(),
        selector: '#emailbox',
        callback: function (responseText, textStatus) {}
    });
    return false; 
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/CagLw/

Comment: Thank you Sparky. Let me see where I get with this. Thanks for your help and sample.

Comment: This worked for me. making sure the mark-up is correct is so important. thanks again.